# What are the advantages of giving the experience to the legacy bosses?

Tags: dragon-quest-9

After beating one of the legacy bosses (Zoma, for instance), I'm offered the choice to let the boss have the experience from the battle.  What are the advantages to doing this?  Is the boss the more likely to drop rare treasure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **advantages** of giving the bosses the experience points is:

- You get more experience from them.
- They get more of a challenge.
- They drop better items ([A full list of item drops](http://www.woodus.com/den/games/dq9ds/legacy_boss_drops.php)).

The **disadvantages**:

- Harder to kill.
- May get more attacks per move, or more abilities.
- You cannot get the item drops, if the boss levels past the range of which they drop.